# Getting ids of recently uploaded files in eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have a view that uploads images using dropzone and this is the controller that commits the data to my model

```
public function product_images(Request $request)
    {
        
        //echo asset('storage/3fb80245e9beb3ce6cbbf68be25a0d0b.jpg');
        //http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/3fb80245e9beb3ce6cbbf68be25a0d0b.jpg
        
        
        $file = new User_files;
        
      if ($request->file('file')) {
        $filePath = $request->file('file');
        $fileName = $filePath->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');
      }
     
     $md5Name = md5_file($request->file('file')->getRealPath());
     $guessExtension = $request->file('file')->guessExtension();
    
      $file->file_name = $filePath->getClientOriginalName();
      $file->file_category = 'user_files';
      $file->file_path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $md5Name.'.'.$guessExtension, 'public');
      $file->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
      $file->file_ai_description = 'ai desc';
      $file->save();

      return response()->json([ 'success' => $fileName ]);
    }
    
    public function removeFile(Request $request)
    {
        $name =  $request->get('name');
        User_files::where(['file_name' => $name])->delete();

        return $name;
    }
```

The files are inserted to the mysql database i am using. However, in order to associate the images uploaded to a particular post, i need to return the ids of the inserted images preferably in a comma delimited list in order to insert them in a  separate table that holds the post.

How can i get all the ids of the inserted images in eloquent?

Comment: every image go through this function and then when all the image are processed, you want to link all the image to the User, is that right ?

Comment: I want to insert every image uploaded and perhaps get the id as soon as its inserted and have them a comma delimited list.

Comment: what about to return this $file or $file->id after the save() method?

Comment: I was thinking this can be done on the side of eloquent, but i can put the ids in an array and return them one by one and combine into a csv with js.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it like this

```
public function product_images(Request $request)
    {
        
        //echo asset('storage/3fb80245e9beb3ce6cbbf68be25a0d0b.jpg');
        //http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/3fb80245e9beb3ce6cbbf68be25a0d0b.jpg
        
        $file = new User_files;
        

         $output = [];  
         if(is_array($_FILES))   
         {  
              foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $name => $value)  
              {  
                   $file_name = explode(".", $_FILES['images']['name'][$name]);  
                   $allowed_ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "webp");  
                    
                        $new_name = uniqid().mt_rand().time() . '.' . $file_name[1];  
                        $sourcePath = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$name];  
                        $targetPath = "uploads/".$new_name;   
                        if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath))  
                        {  
                           
                             //$output .= $targetPath;  
                             array_push($output,'http://localhost:8000/uploads/'.$new_name);
     
                        }                 
                               
              }

        }  

      return response()->json([ 'success' => $output]);
    }
```

and in the dropzone js side

```
Dropzone.options.fileDropzone = {
    paramName: "images",
    url: '{{route('product_images')}}',
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: true, 
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 100,
    maxFilesize: 10000, 
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    removedfile: function(file)
    {
      var name = file.upload.filename;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{route('removeFile')}}',
        data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", name: name},
        success: function (data){
            console.log("File has been successfully removed!!");
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }});
        var fileRef;
        return (fileRef = file.previewElement) != null ?
        fileRef.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
    },
    successmultiple: function (file,  responseText) {

      console.log('csv', responseText);
    },
  }
```

I have decided to insert the images when posting the form since if you posts when inside `product_images` you are likely to end up inserting some of the images and not all. I have looked for a solution on getting the ids of affected rows after a batch insert and i haven't found any.

Uploading Multiple Images in Laravel

Controller method

```
public function create_product_post(Request $request){
        
    
          $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'product_name' => 'required',
                'product_category' => 'required',
                'product_description' => 'required',
                'images' => 'required',
                'images.*' => 'mimes:png,jpg,gif,jpeg,webp|max:2048'
                
            ], [
                'product_name.required' => 'Product Name is required',
                'product_category.required' => 'Product Category Number field is required',
                'product_description.required' => 'Product Description field is required',
                'images.required' => 'Product Images field is required',
            ]);
            
            
           if($request->hasfile('images'))
            {
            foreach($request->file('images') as $file)
            {
                $name = mt_rand().uniqid().'.'.$file->extension();
                $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $name);  
                $uploaded_images_array[] = $name;  
            }
            }

         $data = $request->all();
         $data['product_images'] = json_encode($uploaded_images_array);
         Products::create($data);

        return back()->with('success', 'Products have been successfully added');
        
    }
```

Your model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_name', 'product_category','product_description','product_images'
    ];
}
```

Your blade view

```
<div class="col-12">
<label class="form-field-name p-2">Product Images</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" multiple />
</div>
```

This is a simpler route than dropzone although you should build your own image previews.